# Comparing Faces with Android camera

Tags: android, android-camera, face

How can I use the [facial landmarks](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial), to compare two faces?

The code below sets the landmarks on face:

```
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
Face face = faces.valueAt(i);
for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
    int cx = (int) (landmark.getPosition().x * scale);
    int cy = (int) (landmark.getPosition().y * scale);
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 10, paint);
}
}
```

But the value of those positions changes with a minimum change of the position camera.

Comment: Compare an area instead of a single point.

Comment: that's an entire research field... see OpenCV

Comment: I did that... with the face detect, I cut the picture of the face. But I need to take the same photo, with the same angle. Outherwise, it wouldn't works.

Comment: OpenCV has a lib for detect faces, like the example that I mentionned on question.